# Homework, demonstrate a translation in QFT using the momentum operator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, momentum, fermions

The question is to demonstrate the following relation in case of fermionic field:
$$ e^{i\vec{x_0}.\vec{P}} \psi(\vec{x}) e^{-i\vec{x_0}.\vec{P}} = \psi(\vec{x} - \vec{x_0})$$

where $\psi(\vec{x})$ is a fermionic field and $\vec{P}$ is the momentum operator. I tried several methods but none of them gave the right answer.

Comment: Show us your methods!

Comment: Related (possible duplicates): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43421/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/667146/226902

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$
e^{a\partial_x}f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{a^n\partial_x^n}{n!}f(x)=
\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(x)=f(x+a)
$$
where the last equality is just Taylor series expansion.